# Error while exporting from object structure in maximo

Tags: maximo

error : No data to write to interface table while exporting  from an object structure in maximo

Answer (score 0):

Please check the list tab if you have data to export. If there is no data pulled into the list tab, it will export anything.

if you are not facing this error while exporting the data from the application through application export, please elaborate the error more on which application you are getting it.